# How to create an object with a vector of objects inside

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8, typescript1.5

I using angular 4 to create my website. But I need create a Object with a vecotor of objects inside. This don't work for me. My Code:

Object 1 (disciplinaStatus.module.ts)

```
export class DisciplinaStatus{
 constructor(public codigo: string,
          public nome: string,
          public status: string,
          public professor:string,
          public cargaHoraria:string,
          public nota: number) {}
}
```

Object 2 (historicoData.module.ts)

```
import { DisciplinaStatus } from './disciplinaStatus.model';

export  class HistoricoData{
   constructor(public periodo: string,
          public historico: DisciplinaStatus[]) {} //The Problem stay here!!!
}
```

My component ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DisciplinaStatus } from './models/disciplinaStatus.model';
import { HistoricoData } from './models/historicoData.model';

@Component({
     selector: 'historico-a-component',
     templateUrl: './historico-a.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./historico-a.component.css']
})
export class HistoricoAComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(historico: HistoricoData[]) {

  historico = [
      new HistoricoData('2016/1', [
          new DisciplinaStatus('001','Redes 1','Completo','Everthon Valadão','60',71.5),
          new DisciplinaStatus('002','Compiladores','Completo','Walace','60',45.5)
      ]),
      new HistoricoData('2016/2', [
          new DisciplinaStatus('001','AED','Completo','Diego Melo','60',22.5),
          new DisciplinaStatus('002','Teoria','Completo','Diego Melo','60',89.5)
      ])
  ];
}
```

The ERROR:

> ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:7 ERROR Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HistoricoAComponent -> Array]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HistoricoAComponent -> Array]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Array!
>       at *NullInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1209)
>       at resolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1507)
>       at tryResolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1449)
>       at StaticInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1317)
>       at resolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1507)
>       at tryResolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1449)
>       at StaticInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1317)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11051)
>       at NgModuleRef*.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12284)
>       at resolveDep (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12774)

Comment: Looks like you are using the constructor to declare a property. Just declare the propert first in the class and remove it from the constructor parameters so that angular do not believe it should inject somrthing since you are overwriting it. The reference history with this.history.

Comment: Thanks JGoodgive. This working fine.

Comment: Great. Added it as answer so that you can mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the constructor to declare a property. Just declare the propert first in the class and remove it from the constructor parameters so that angular do not believe it should inject somrthing since you are overwriting it.